# Can anyone tell me why my paragraph links are unclickable?

Tags: html, css

I have two anchor tags that are not clickable for some reason. One link should open up so clients can send me an email to my email address. The other link should open up a phone or app so clients can contact me via phone.

I cannot figure out why only these two links are not working. I am using a bootstrap template so maybe there is something in this section (jquery?) that is preventing the links from working as they normally would. The icons in the unordered list in the same section don't seem to have this issue.

```html
<section class="ftco-section about-section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex" data-scrollax-parent="true">
            <div class="col-md-4 author-img" style="background-image: url(images/author-1.jpg);" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '-70%'}"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 wrap ftco-animate">
              <div class="about-desc">
                <h1 class="bold-text">About</h1>
                <div class="p-5">
                  <h2 class="mb-5">Hi! I'm Matthew Mullins</h2>
                  <p>I thrive working on large, commercial, information heavy site designs. I have an emphasis on ease of use & simplicity. My idea of great visual design: when it enhances the user experience, & doesn't get in the way.</p>
                  
                  <ul class="ftco-footer-social list-unstyled mt-4">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-behance"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-dribbble"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-instagram"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-google"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  
                  <p>Email: <a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">example@gmail.com</a></p>
                  <p>Phone: <a href="#">(442)-224-4005</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I was expecting the links to open up to their respective locations. Instead, the text is blue but the mouse does not indicate there is a link underneath.

Comment: Would most likely be something with the CSS on your links, as it works in the example you gave. Try setting `cursor: pointer` on those links, which should show that they are clickable links.

If that doesn't work please include your CSS.

Comment: Hey Callum, Thanks a lot! That did the trick. I wonder what was causing this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

Seems to be something with the CSS on your links, as it works in the example you gave. Try setting `cursor: pointer;` on those links, which should show that they are clickable links.

Something in your Bootstrap or other styles must have been overriding the default cursor as pointer on link elements.